# Xpath: extract value from element using text outside of element

Tags: html, xpath

I want to extract the @name values for the input elements below.

```
<div style="style info">
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" onchange="doSomething;"/>
Mobile
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" onchange="doSomething;"/>
Event
<br/>
</div>
```

In the above example, I want to extract the name ("name1") that relates to "Mobile".

I need a one-line xpath that can retrieve this information for me.  I have tried

```
//div[normalize-space(text())='Mobile']/preceding-sibling::input/@name

//div[normalize-space(text())='Mobile']/input/@name

//div[normalize-space(.)='Mobile']/preceding-sibling::input/name
```

and several other guesses after combing the archives here, but I have not found anything that works (I am somewhat new to XML, as you can no doubt tell; sorry if my guesses seem haphazard).

Thanks in advance for your answers, and please let me know if there are any clarifications or corrections I can make that will assist in solving this.  Your help is extremely appreciated!

NOTE: XSLT is not an option for me

Answer (score 1):

You want to locate the text node of interest first, rather than the div. From there, you can go to the preceding-sibling as you have tried.

Try:

```
//text()[normalize-space() = "Mobile"]/preceding-sibling::input/@name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//div/input[normalize-space(following-sibling::text()[1])='Mobile']/@name
```